# timedatectl does not remain synced after reboot on Ubundu 18.04

Tags: ntp

Today I noticed that my computer clock was off after rebooting.  timedatectl showed that it was not synchronized:

```
kfank@kfank-VirtualBox:~/tmp$ timedatectl
                      Local time: Fri 2020-06-05 11:58:44 PDT
                  Universal time: Fri 2020-06-05 18:58:44 UTC
                        RTC time: Fri 2020-06-05 18:58:45
                       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

I followed some instructions for starting the service again and found that it was then synchronized (System clock sychronized: yes):

```
kfank@kfank-VirtualBox:~/tmp$ sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
kfank@kfank-VirtualBox:~/tmp$ timedatectl
                      Local time: Fri 2020-06-05 12:12:16 PDT
                  Universal time: Fri 2020-06-05 19:12:16 UTC
                        RTC time: Fri 2020-06-05 19:12:17
                       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
kfank@kfank-VirtualBox:~/tmp$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd
kfank@kfank-VirtualBox:~/tmp$ timedatectl
                      Local time: Fri 2020-06-05 12:12:41 PDT
                  Universal time: Fri 2020-06-05 19:12:41 UTC
                        RTC time: Fri 2020-06-05 19:12:42
                       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

However, after a reboot it was right back to where I started:

```
kfank@kfank-VirtualBox:~$ timedatectl
                      Local time: Fri 2020-06-05 12:18:19 PDT
                  Universal time: Fri 2020-06-05 19:18:19 UTC
                        RTC time: Fri 2020-06-05 19:18:20
                       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Here is the status which I believe shows it the service to enabled (so I would expect it to start automatically) but also not running:

```
kfank@kfank-VirtualBox:~$ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
```

Can someone give some direction on how to fix and/or debug this?

Comment: are you dual booting with Windows?  Windows derives time from the local time zone.  Pretty much every other operating system, including Ubuntu derives time from UTC.  This can cause the time to be changed when switching between operating systems.

Comment: @Nmath: Ubuntu is running in VM under a windows host so it is independent.  The problem is occurring because the timesyncd service is not running.